# what is the fastest way to copy mysql row?

Tags: php, mysql, copy, row

I've got to copy some mysql rows before pages load. I tried to copy it to a temp table, something like this:

```
 mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tbl SELECT * FROM subject WHERE ID='$ID'");
 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tmp_tbl SET ID=NULL");
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO subject SELECT * FROM tmp_tbl");
 mysqli_query($con,"DROP TABLE tmp_tbl");`
```

It works pretty slow. Does just copying it in the regular ugly way would be faster?

**edit**: when you want to update multiple rows you can do somthing like this:

```
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO subject (Primary,AnotherID, COLB, COLC)
SELECT NULL,'$a', COLB, COLC
FROM subject WHERE AnotherID='$someID'");
```

You must put a null in the primary key, otherwise its doesnt work

Comment: Did you check the outcome of `explain` on your queries? Add it to your posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly speed this up, but the overall speed will be determined by the number of rows in the `subject` table - after all your queries double its size.

For this example I'm assuming the `subject` table columns are `ID`, `ColA`, `ColB`, and `ColC`, and that `ID` is an auto-incrementing primary key:

```
INSERT INTO subject (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM subject
```

The key is to specify every column *except* `ID` when inserting/selecting.

Comment: And if i need to copy more than one row, is it still faster?

Comment: It will be faster because it uses only one command instead of four. If your `subject` table has lots of rows (say thousands), it will be faster than what you're doing now but it will still be slow because copying thousands of rows takes time no matter how you do it.

Comment: Im trying to do it with "WHERE NotUniqueID='$ID'", because i've got to copy couple of rows. any way to do it this way?

Comment: Just tack it on to the `SELECT` like you normally would: `FROM subject WHERE ...`. If you're asking specifically how to do it in mysqli I'm afraid I can't help; I usually use PDO.

Comment: Its only works when the select selects 1 row. I think the only way to do it is on a loop

Comment: I tried a multi-row insert/select from a table into itself before I posted my answer above, and it worked. My test table included an auto-increment primary key. There may be something else causing the problem - it could be the introduction of the `WHERE` since then, or it could be something else. Could you post your table structure and your exact query in the question?

Comment: Ok, its works for me now. i had to put NULL in the primary key, ill post it on my question, thanks alot